# Ghost outline of bar in Extjs bar chart

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs-chart

I have a bar chart with filtering facility available. Whenever I filter the chart's store. There is a ghost bar present in the chart. Please find the attached screenshot.

Please let me know how to prevent the chart behave like this.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I have no idea. Please show your code, maybe someone could help. Without code there's no chance ...

Comment: It is just filtering the store attached to the chart. When the data gets filtered there is only one bar left to represent the data in store. But the ghost bar is off the store's data. It must be rendering issue. All the configurations are normal.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle ?